# android center image in header but fill whole listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view and at runtime I add a header to it with a header_layout as below.

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/alertslayoutheader"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/dash_vector_alpha2"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="40dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text360"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-normal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text=" 360°"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="38dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Using an ImageView, I place a picture in centere of the header. I am able to achieve this. But then(as expected I guess) the image gets cuts-off below header and does not show up bottom parts in rows below.

I want it to not get cut off by rows below. I want the header image to fill rest of rows below. The image in header also needs to scroll.

Using a padding + setting it as background for whole listview doesn't help as resolutions vary.

appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please, pull out the TextView of your LinearLayout (and get rid of the latter).

Comment: didn't work. FWIW:  I have my list items also have transparent background

Comment: But still you don't need a useless container (which is only bad for performances).

Comment: agreed. point taken.